# Trouble with Method undefined for a type Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java programming and having a hard time understanding the use of methods and how to use them in the code. I know this is really basic things and I'm trying, it's just hard to grasp at first. So tl;dr I don't quite understand this error or how to fix it.

```
public class TriangleInfo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Triangle versuch = createTriangle();
    }

    public static createTriangle() {
        double side1 = 90;
        double side2 = 80;
        double hypotenuse = getHypotenuse();
        Triangle thisTriangle = new Triangle(side1, side2, hypotenuse);     
        return thisTriangle;
    }

    public static double getHypotenuse() {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(side1, 2) + Math.pow(side2, 2));
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> The method createTriangle() is undefined for the type TriangleInfo

I also have this written in another file:

```
public class Triangle {
    double side1;
    double side2;
    double hypotenuse;

    // Konstrukturen
    public Triangle(double sideOne, double sideTwo, double hypotenuse) {
        this.sideOne = sideOne;
        this.sideTwo = sideTwo;
        this.hypotenuse = hypotenuse;
    }
}
```

Could someone please help me understand this error and how to correct it? Thank you!

Comment: createTriangle has no return type

Comment: Also your static access in getHypotenuse is most likely not what you want. I'd suggest to follow any good guide/book on basic java.

Comment: Look at `Math.hypot`.

Comment: If any of the answers helped you, please select them as your answer.

Comment: This is late, because things got a little bit tossed up here with the current corona situation. But I wanted to thank you all for taking the time to help a beginner. I took good advice here and researched a bit more. Thank you all :) Once again, sorry for my really late response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that your method `createTriangle()` doesn't have a return type. Since you are returning a `Triangle`, you need to add that.

```
public static Triangle createTriangle() {
```

And continue with your normal code.

Also, a good catch from @JO3-W3B-D3V, the `side1` and `side2` are not globally accessible in the class, so you need to do:

```
public static double getHypotenuse(double side1, double side2) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(side1, 2) + Math.pow(side2, 2));
}
```

So, your complete `createTriangle()` function becomes:

```
public static Triangle createTriangle(){
    double side1 = 90;
    double side2 = 80;
    double hypotenuse = getHypotenuse(side1, side2);
    Triangle thisTriangle = new Triangle(side1, side2, hypotenuse);  
    return thisTriangle;   
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was very helpful

Comment: @Taurus Glad it helped!

Answer (score -1):

Okay, first of all, looking at the code you've provided, the method `createTriangle` does not have a return type specified, all you need to do here is refactor it like so:

`public static Triangle createTriangle() { // Body of the method...`

Then there's the matter of the `getHypotenuse` method, since it has no reference to the values `side1` or `side2`, you need to either alter it such that the these variables are properties within the class, or you can update the method & the caller, like so:

**Caller**

`double hypotenuse = getHypotenuse(side1, side2);`

**Method**

`public static double getHypotenuse(double side1, double side2) { // Body of the method...`

Finally, in the `Triangle` class, you have the property names stated as `side`, but in the constructor of the `Triangle` class, you try to assign `this.sideOne`, it should either be `side1` in the constructor, **or** you should change the name(s) of the class properties.

### Summary

To be fair, I appreciate that you're a beginner & to be fair, you weren't too far from having a working implementation.

---

### Complete Solution

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class TriangleInfo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Triangle versuch = createTriangle();
    }

    public static Triangle createTriangle() {
        double side1 = 90;
        double side2 = 80;

        double hypotenuse = getHypotenuse(side1, side2);
        Triangle thisTriangle = new Triangle(side1, side2, hypotenuse);
        return thisTriangle;
    }

    public static double getHypotenuse(double side1, double side2) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(side1, 2) + Math.pow(side2, 2));
    }
}

class Triangle {
    double side1;
    double side2;
    double hypotenuse;

    // Konstrukturen
    public Triangle(double sideOne, double sideTwo, double hypotenuse) {
        this.side1 = sideOne;
        this.side2 = sideTwo;
        this.hypotenuse = hypotenuse;
    }
}
```

Comment: @GauravMall Just to be clear I haven't downvoted either as you both do still answer the question, however you both go to much into answering something that is unrelated to the OPs question. The focus should be solely the OPs issue, you're taking focus away from the question at hand that can cause confusion to other users when they come along and see this question and want an answer. You can always be too helpful that it creates more of a problem. You should stay on track and focus on the question, a side mention is fine but not the whole answer.

Comment: @Popeye You're right. We got off track a bit and yes we should focus on the problem more. But I still think it was an interesting conversation :)

Comment: @besartm I've only down-voted answers that I genuinely believe to be of a very poor quality. You don't get points for down-voting others answers, if anything you lose points, fyi.

Comment: @GauravMall there is no issue with having a conversation as long as it doesn't take focus away from the issue that they are asking. If it goes to much into something else then the best thing is to start a conversation in a room (Chat rooms)

Comment: @Popeye I can't say that you're wrong, but considering the OP is a beginner, I thought it's best to provide as much help as possible. Embracing the community spirit & all! :)

Comment: @Popeye Couldn't agree more with you!

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V consider as well those who are going to be looking for an answer to the same issue, will they want to read through everything that is unrelated to the question that has been asked? This normally results in more of the same questions being asked because people loose focus in there answers.

Comment: @besartm vote fixing will just get you band from the service. If someone has just gone through the answers downvoting all answers except their own the system will deal with it already.

Comment: Just to make clear I do this all the time and loose focus, as a programmer I feel it's in our nature to help if we see issues in code.